# Best Agile template for TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs, agile, scrum

I've just installed TFS 2010, and would like to use TFS in the most Agile way.

I've seen http://scrumforteamsystem.com, are they're any other good templates you can suggest?

Cheers,
Ash.

Answer (score 10):

@Ash, Yess indeed there is. There is now an official Visual Studio 2010 Scrum Process Template that has been created in conjunction with many Scrum guys and Ken Schwaber.

[Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1.0](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=197304)

Process template from Microsoft for Scrum teams.  Scrum is an iterative, incremental framework for project management and agile software development.  This template includes work items and reports to help your Scrum team be successful.

Learn more about Scrum and the Visual Studio Scrum 1.0 template.

- [Visual Studio Scrum 1.0 Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731587.aspx)
- [Learn More About Scrum (Ken Schwaber)](http://www.scrum.org/)
- [Agile Principles and Values by Jeff Sutherland](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997578.aspx)

I use this template with TFS 2010 and it is a 1-1 Scrum template unlike Agile5 which is a generic agile that has instructions for Scrum.

The [Professional Scrum Developer (.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff433643.aspx) course also uses this template.

I also use an add-on tool to TFS to help with the management of the Backlog and Work In Progress. [Urban Turtle](http://urbanturtle.com/) provides just awesome capabilities on top of TFS to add the Task board and backlog management functionality that comes with the Conchnago template.

Comment: +1 for the VS Scrum template and PSD course.

Comment: I wish MS has had published it 3 months ago. That time we were seriously searching for a Scrum template. As MS didn't have such a thing at the time we started to use "Scrum for Team System". Now many training courses has been done based on it and 4 project has been started with it. Now it's very hard for us to switch to Microsoft's scrum template.

Comment: I feel your pain. I do a lot of migrations for clients from Scrum for Team System to other templates and it is frawt with pain :) I have sucessfully micgrated the projects using the "TFS Integration Platform"

Comment: I regularly publish scripts on upgrading and migrating process templates. I have a new post going up on Wednesday 12th June 2014 on http://nakedalm.com/blog

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft recently released Visual Studio Scrum 1.0 Process Template.

You can get the Template here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/59ac03e3-df99-4776-be39-1917cbfc5d8e

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Urban Turtle Scrum tool for TFS.

http://urbanturtle.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should also take a look at Eylean Board. It is a great visual tool that offers two-way integration with TFS and a template scrum board that allows you to apply scrum practices.

[Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com/scrum?utm_source=website&utm_medium=text&utm_campaign=DMaction)